# Replace characters in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have an JSON and I would find strings in it which are a part of the values.

For instance:

```
type: 'this.is.a.test'
```

I would like to replace all 'this.is.a.' in my entire JSON that only 'test' remains.

Here is my code. But It do not work:

```
var old = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"this.is.a."/g, '""'); //convert to JSON string
var d = JSON.parse(old); //convert back to array
```

Comment: Why do you want to process the json as a string? Json is an object, go throught the items in it and modify the values directly. Add example json in the question.

Comment: Can you clarify the pattern you want to use for the text replace? Is there some sort of pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with `JSON.stringify`, you should pass a replacer function which calls `.replace` on all strings before they get returned for stringification:

```js
const data = {
  foo: [
    'bar this.is.a. bar',
    {
      prop: 'propVal this.is.a. propVal'
    }
  ]
};

const str = JSON.stringify(
  data,
  (key, val) => {
    if (typeof val === 'string') {
      return val.replace(/this\.is\.a\./g, '');
    }
    return val;
  }
);

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Comment: OP's regular expression  contains double-quote characters so I would expect they're wanting to match entire string keys / values. Of course, OP's question is unclear and I could be totally wrong

Comment: He said that, eg, for `type: 'this.is.a.test'`, *I would like to replace all* `'this.is.a.'` *in my entire JSON that only* `'test'` *remains*, which seems pretty clear to me

Comment: D'oh, that's what I get for jumping straight to the code. Nice one

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your `JSON`, and you can change the structure as you need.

**Here is a working DEMO**

```js
var data = {
    a: "this.is.a. test",
    b: "test this.is.a.",
    c: "test this.is.a. test"
}

for (var prop in data) {
  data[prop] = data[prop].replace(/this.is.a./g, '')
}

console.log(data);
```

[Here is a fiddle link, you can check console](https://jsfiddle.net/sq0fy9ja/)

Comment: can anyone say the reason for downvlte?

Comment: @mm1975, please run the snippet and check